# Return boolean with php to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, authentication

I don't really know AJAX well for now. I'd like to know if, after calling a PHP file from JavaScript with AJAX, I can return a Boolean value.

To be more specific, I'll explain my code.

I am making a 2 steps login in only page. So first of all, the user has to enter his email address. If this one exists in the database, the user must enter his password (without loading a new page). Then if the password is good, he is successfully logged in.

So I have a function called when submitting the mail that I haven't yet written (mail is a string coming from `<input type="email" name="email" onsubmit="mailCheck(this.value)">`):

```
function mailCheck(mail) {
    for (i = 0; i < mail.length; i++) {
        if (mail[i] == "") {
            document.getElementById("input").style.background = "#FFDDEE";
        }
    }
    if (!existing(mail)) {
        document.getElementById("input").style.background = "#FFDDEE";
    } else {
        //TODO: GO TO NEXT STEP (PASSWORD)
    }
}
function existing(mail) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //TODO: USE mailCheck.php
    return false;
}
```

So here, I'm focusing on how to know if the mail is found in the database. So my file mailCheck.php contains:

```
<?php
session_start();
$mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);
$page = htmlspecialchars($_GET['reply']);

//Connect to the database (done)
//Ask the database (done)

//Act according to the answer of the database
if (!$result) {
       //TODO: RETURN FALSE WITH AJAX
} else {
       $_SESSION['ID'] = $result['ID'];
       //Others variables (done)
       $_SESSION['login'] = false;
       //TODO: RETURN TRUE WITH AJAX
}
?>
```

So do you know how can my function existing(mail) know if the mail is found in the database during the process in mailCheck.php?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Bastien

Comment: In the function `mailCheck` - what is the type of `mail`? string,array,object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ajax is essentially asynchronous you cannot reliably return a value - you could use the `fetch` api which is built around the `Promise` ideology which would allow you to return a value or you could use the ajax callback to continue processing, based upon the response from the server, when the mail checking has been completed.

With the `fetch` api you can chain together many different requests so if there is a dependency on a previous value being true or false etc you can wait for it to be available which you cannot do in ajax ( other than using callbacks and nested ajax requests )

```
function mailCheck( mail ) {
    for( i = 0; i < mail.length; i++ ) {/* is this an array? */
        if ( mail[i] == "" ) document.getElementById("input").style.background = "#FFDDEE";
    }
    var _callback=function( response ){
        if( response===false ){
            document.getElementById("input").style.background = "#FFDDEE";
        } else {
            //TODO: GO TO NEXT STEP (PASSWORD)
        }
    }

    existing.call( this, mail, _callback );

}

function existing( mail, callback ) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response );
    }
    xhr.open('POST','mailcheck.php',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send( 'mail='+mail );
}
```

A basic demo of using the `fetch` api ~ quite complicated when compared to ajax but ultimately more flexible when done correctly.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        ob_clean();

        $json=array('error');
        $_POST['time']=microtime();

        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root'; 
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
        $dbname =   'xxx';
        $db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


        switch( $_POST['action'] ){
            case 'checkmail':
                /* db lookup and other tests */
                $email=filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL ), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
                $status=false;

                $sql='select `username` from `users` where `email`=?';
                $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

                if( $stmt ){

                    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email );
                    $result = $stmt->execute();

                    if( $result ){
                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $stmt->bind_result( $username );
                        $stmt->fetch();
                        $stmt->close();
                        $db->close();

                        if( $username ) {
                            $_POST['username']=$username;
                            $status=true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $status=false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $status=false;
                }

                $_POST['status']=$status;
            break;
            case 'login':
                /* validate user login */
                $email=filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL ), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
                $password=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
                $status=false;

                $sql='select `username`,`token` from `users` where `email`=? and `password`=?';
                $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );


                if( $stmt ){

                    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password );
                    $result = $stmt->execute();

                    if( $result ){
                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $stmt->bind_result( $username, $token );
                        $stmt->fetch();
                        $stmt->close();
                        $db->close();

                        if( $username ) {
                            $_POST['username']=$username;
                            $_POST['token']=$token;
                            $status=true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $status=false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $status=false;
                }
                $_POST['status']=$status;
            break;
        }


        $json = json_encode( $_POST );

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true, 200 );
        exit( $json );
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Chained Fetch</title>

        <script>
            var options={
                once:false,
                capture:false,
                passive:false
            };

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

                document.querySelector('form > input[type="button"]').onclick=function(event){

                    var stack=[];
                    var url=location.href;
                    var mail=document.querySelector('form > input[name="email"]');
                    var password=document.querySelector('form > input[name="password"]');

                    var _final=function(r){
                        alert( r );
                    }
                    var _isvalid=function( r ){
                        if( !r.status )throw new Error( r.action+' failed' );
                        return r.status;
                    }

                    /* the urls could be totally different php scripts */
                    stack.push({
                        url:url, /* checkmail.php */
                        config:{
                            method:'POST',
                            mode:'cors',
                            credentials:'include',
                            headers:{ 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },
                            body:'action=checkmail&email='+mail.value
                        }
                    });
                    stack.push({
                        url:url,/* login.php */
                        config:{
                            method:'POST',
                            mode:'cors',
                            credentials:'include',
                            headers:{ 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },
                            body:'action=login&password='+password.value+'&email='+mail.value
                        }
                    });





                    fetch( stack[0].url, stack[0].config )
                        .then( response => response.json() )
                        .then( data => _isvalid( data ) )
                        .then( data => fetch( stack[1].url, stack[1].config ) )
                        .then( response => response.json() )
                        .then( data => _isvalid( data ) )
                        .then( _final )
                        .catch( err => alert( err.message ) );

                }
            },options );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type='email' name='email' />
            <input type='password' name='password' value='knickers' />
            <input type='button' value='Login' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First of all, mail is a string. Then, I don't know at all this API. So with your code I'll try to understand, do I have to put something in the mailCheck.php file as an "answer" (where I put return true or false) or does the code understand automatically?

Comment: yes, send a response back from the php to the ajax callback

Comment: Wow it's quite complicated, but I'll understand after all. So thanks a lot for the help, I'll work on it now.

Comment: You might find https://javascript.info/promise-chaining and https://davidwalsh.name/fetch useful - there are lots of other examples out there on the interwebs